# Количество товара в заказе

Tags: php

У каждого товара есть поле с его количеством в корзине: `<input id="qtyyy" class="product_qty" type="number" value="'.$item['qty'].'" min="1" max="50">`
Передаю в value изначально `$item['qty']`, что равняется 1 для любого товара. Какое бы я количество товара в `input` в корзине не указал, в заказ передается все равно 1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обновлять значение `value` каждый раз когда оно меняется на странице, чтобы в заказе отображалось верное количество каждого товара?

Comment: Читайте, как работает `input` и для чего нужен атрибут `name`

Comment: Либо, я так понимаю, мне просто нужно изменять значение переменной ```$item['qty']``` по нажатию кнопки "+" или "-", это должно помочь? Как это можно реализовать на JS?

Comment: Вы меняете value, но как его передаете? Через форму по action? Если да, то Вы просто не передаете данные, для форм у всех полей должен стоять атрибут `name`,  чтобы передать эти данные.